# What is the best way to determine if a URL belongs to the current domain in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url

I have a URL. It might be relative (e.g. not start with https://, etc.), or it might not be (starts with https://, etc.).

How can I determine if this URL refers to the same domain as window.location?

(I'm creating a XMLHttpRequest and adding a cookie to it. Can only add the cookie if the URL I'm requesting is the same as the one I'm at. It's a secret cookie.)

Comment: "It might be relative..." A relative path automatically belongs to the current domain by definition. You only really need to worry about absolute paths.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is actually to leverage the DOM: when you insert a URL into an `<a>` tag, the browser will actually resolve the URL immediately—i.e. when you retrieve the element's `href` attribute using JS, it will return an absolute path.

Then, you can simply check if the resolved path contains [`window.location.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/origin):

```js
function doesUrlBelongsToCurrentDomain(url) {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  
  return link.href.includes(window.location.origin);
}

console.log(doesUrlBelongsToCurrentDomain('https://google.com')); // false
console.log(doesUrlBelongsToCurrentDomain('./relative-link'));    // true
console.log(doesUrlBelongsToCurrentDomain('/relative-link'));     // true
```

For a ES5-compliant version, swap [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) with [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
return link.href.indexOf(window.location.origin) !== -1;
```

Also, if your browser does not support `window.location.origin`, you will need to construct it manually:

```
var origin = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');
```

...therefore, the IE11-compatible version (if IE11 support is absolutely needed), will be as follow:

```
function doesUrlBelongsToCurrentDomain(url) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;

  var origin = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');

  return link.href.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) from the url to test, and compare it to the current location origin:

```
const sameOrigin = new URL('URL_TO_TEST').origin === window.location.origin;
```